# Is it possible to import the Office 2011's themes (for Mac) to use them in Office 2007 for windows?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, office-for-mac

Is there a way to import(convert) the PowerPoint themes from office 2011 (for mac) to Office 2007 or later for Windows (supposing you own them both)? The themes included with Office for mac come in a great variety as opposed to Office 2007 for Windows..